# Pentaho, adding extra information to a DataBase

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a transformation that downloads information from a JSON file, which I put in a database.

I want from an excel to add a missing code in the JSON to add it to my database.

Excel contains the entire list of city codes and their names, but in the JSON they appear repeated since I have information for years and I would need to add the code of the cities without data in the JSON file so that the final application reports that these cities have no data

I try to use merge transformation without results, and I want to add that city codes to my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the merge join step (joining probably on the city name) and using the Left or Right outer join options, so that cities without json data are also added to the output stream.